# Average of several spectrograms in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrogram

I have many data segments and I can make a spectogram of a single one x:

```
F = [50:200];
[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(x,window,Fs/2,F,Fs)
```

I want to calculate the average of all the spectrograms (one spectrogram per segment). All segments are the same length, so I assume F and T will be the same for the average spectrogram.

Now I calculate the average for P (of all segments) and I think this will result in an average spectrogram when plotted with:

```
surf(T,F,10*log10(AverageP),'edgecolor','none');
```

Is this logically correct?

Comment: if you are trying advanced spectrograms in Matlab you should download tftb and run tfrspwv spectrogram routine, it's an academic very advanced spectrogram which averages in the time and frequency domains independently.